# Socket.io in Angular not working in a .then()

Tags: angular, api, socket.io, nestjs, peerjs

So, when i run this code in a component:

```
        const videoholder = <HTMLDivElement>(
          document.querySelector('#videoholder')
        );
        const myPeer = new Peer(this.userid, {
          host: '/',
          port: 3001,
        });
        const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
        myVideo.muted = true;

        navigator.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true,
          })
          .then((stream) => {
            this.dmService.getCallJoin().subscribe((message: any) => {
              console.log(message);
              console.log(message.userId + ' ' + message.callId);
              console.log(stream);
              if (this.callInfo.callid == message.callId) {
              }
          });
            addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);
          });
```

The dmService.getCallJoin() is working outside the `.then()`, but inside the `.then()` it runs one time or i don't know, but its not working.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Heres some more code:

**Angular service part**

```
  public joinCall(data: {callId: any, userId: any}) {
    this.socket.emit('joinRoom', data);
  }

  public getCallJoin() {
    let data$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
      console.log("ZSALMASZOSZ")
      this.socket.on('userConnected', (data) => {
      console.log("ZSALMASZOSZ IN")
      data$.next(data);
    });

    return data$.asObservable();
  }
```

**NestJS**

```
  @SubscribeMessage("joinRoom")
  async joinRoom(@MessageBody() body: any) {
    this.server.emit("userConnected", {
      callId: body.callId,
      userId: body.userId,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing Promises and Observables is not a good practice. You can convert a promise to observable with the [from](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from) operator and then you could chain the observables with the [pipe](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators) operator.

Alternatively, you can use [async/await](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html) to simplify your code.
And you should also take care to unsubscribe from your subscriptions to prevent memory leaks.

```
   private subscription: Subscription;
   ...

   const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
   this.subscription = this.dmService.getCallJoin().subscribe((message: any) => {
              console.log(message);
              console.log(message.userId + ' ' + message.callId);
              console.log(stream);
              if (this.callInfo.callid == message.callId) {
              }
          });
     
     ...
     
     ngOnDestroy() {
       if(this.subscription) {
         this.subscription.unsubscribe()
       }
     }
```